# If I want to beta test other people's Windows Phone apps where do I find those apps?

Tags: apps, store, beta

It seems that developers are keen to have their apps beta tested but where do you go if you want to offer to test? Where do you find apps which haven't yet reached the marketplace?

Comment: Off topic. Should be on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: I disagree, anyone interested in Windows Phone could find it useful / interesting to know how and where to participate in beta app testing.

Comment: Its a software development issue - clearly not a fit for this site.  I agree with @karancan - should be on SO.

Comment: From http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic : "Developing/programming for Windows Phone (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)"

Comment: i'm not asking about developing/programming, i'm asking a marketplace/community question. where/how do you access those apps which are about to hit the marketplace. might be fun to evaluate them and assist the community/ecosystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to beta test you have to find a website/facebook page/twitter etc where they announce that they are beta testing. You then send them your MS Account info and they send you a link which is only for your account.